# Why is this very simple AJAX script not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Just trying to make a very simple AJAX, but nothing. Thanks!

```
<script>
function update()
{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  var str='test';

xmlhttp.open("GET","localhost/userupdate.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

and the php page localhost/userupdate.php (WAMP)

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];
echo $q;
?>
```

Comment: You should use `http://localhost` in your `xmlhttp.open`

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You do nothing with the onreadystatechange. After you correct the url, you would just call the server and that is all it would do.

Comment: What do you want it to do? You have to tell us what it's supposed to do before we can tell you why it isn't.

Comment: Because you arent doing anything with the data. Try saving something to a file instead. You will see it works fine.

Comment: Try using `http://127.0.0.1` especially if you're trying this on a WAMP stack

Comment: "very simple" ajax could would simply use jquery: `$.get('userupdate.php', {q: str});`

Comment: I see you mention IE5.  Did you copy this from a decade-old tutorial?  Even IE6 should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should use the full URL in your `xmlhttp.open` -- `http://localhost/userupdate.php`. If the `userupdate.php` file is in the same directory as this script, then you can simply use `userupdate.php` instead.

Second, you're not doing anything with the response. Since the response is a string, you can use `responseText` property to retrieve it.

```
function update() {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    var str = 'test';

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/userupdate.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: The code in the original question likely executes the ajax call to the server, and returns data - the issue being pointed out in this answer, and many of the above comments, is that the data that is being returned from the server, is not being 'handled'. This answer encapsulates an event response to the OnReadyStateChange method, which will output whatever is returned from the server in the console.

It's my personal practice to often times pass a 'container' to my ajax callback method, that then replaces whatever is in said 'container' with whatever is returned from the server.

Comment: I tried all of the above to include http://localhost/userupdate.php, http://127.0.0.1/userupdate.php, localhost/userupdate.php, and /userupdate.php.  Also, pasted the code above.  Still nothing.  Maybe a WAMP issue?

Comment: @user2734634: How are you calling this function? Add a `<body onload="update()"> </body>` at the bottom of the page and check your browser console.

Comment: Thanks Amal!  Works great now.